# Javascript Check if <p> exists in <div>

Tags: javascript, html

I'm completely new to Javascript. I am trying to create a p tag in a div (which contains the number 0) when the div is first mouse-overed, and the number in the p tag increases during each mouse-over.

How do I use the if-else statement to check if the p tag is in the div at the first place?

```
<script>
function increaseNum(x){
var i;
if (document.getElementById('mcount').contains("p")){
i++;
}else{
number = document.createElement("P");
mcount.appendChild(number);
i=0;
}
number.innerHTML = i;
}
</script>


<html>
<div id="mcount" onmouseover="increaseNum(this)"></div>
</html>
```

Any sort of help is appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: You could check whether or not ``document.getElementById("mcount").querySelector("p")`` returns an element

Answer (score 3):

> Check if `<p>` exists in `<div>`

We can check for this using:

```
var number = document.querySelector('#mcount p')
if (number !== null) {
   console.log('<p> exists in <div>')
} else {
   console.log('<p> does not exists in <div> yet.')
}
```

Next, you can update your code using `document.querySelector` like this:

```js
var i;
function increaseNum(x) {
  var mcount = document.querySelector('#mcount');
  var number = document.querySelector('#mcount p');
  if (number !== null) {
    i++;
  } else {
    var elem = document.createElement("P");
    mcount.appendChild(elem);
    number = document.querySelector('#mcount p');
    i = 0;
  }
  number.innerHTML = i;
}
increaseNum(0);
```

```css
p{font-size:2rem;padding-left:1rem;border:1px solid #eee}
```

```html
<div id="mcount" onmouseover="increaseNum(this)"></div>
```

Also, `document.getElementById('mcount').contains("p")` is not correct as The [`Node.contains()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains) method only works on node elements but here you are simply passing a string like `"p"`. So, we can use `document.querySelector('#mcount p')` here instead and it will be `null` until `p` is added to `#mcount` node and after that it will not null and we can use that in our `if..else` logic.

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.querySelector('#dfp-tlb p') != null` in your `if condition`

Answer (score 0):

Please find another answer:

```js
let i=0;

//get the div tag
var mcount = document.querySelector('#mcount');
mcount.textContent=i;

function increaseNum() {

  //getting the number of p tags present in div
  var number = document.querySelectorAll('#mcount p').length;
  if (number){
    console.log(`Numner of p tags are : ${i}`);
  }

  //Creating the node and appending
  var elem = document.createElement("P");
  i ++;
  elem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(i))
  mcount.appendChild(elem);
  
}
```

```css
div{
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="mcount" onmouseover="increaseNum()"></div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const setup = () => {
 const exist = document.querySelector('#mccount p') !== null;
  const existChild = document.querySelector('#mccount > p') !== null;
  console.log(exist);
  console.log(existChild);

}
window.addEventListener('load', setup);
```

```html
<div id="mccount">
  <div>
    <p>
    
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative you can do that only works on children is playing with nodes. Still I won't recommand this solution. But it exist:

```js
const setup = () => {
 const mccount = document.querySelector('#mccount')
  console.log(mccount);
  const existChild = [...mccount.childNodes].some(node => node.nodeName === 'P');
  console.log(existChild);

}
window.addEventListener('load', setup);
```

Overal `document.querySelector('#mccount p') !== null` or `document.querySelector('#mccount > p') !== null` would be a lot easyer to use.